# JQuery Toggle not working on Wordpress website

Tags: jquery, wordpress, toggle

Hi guys I'm having some trouble using JQuery on my Wordpress website to toggle a div. I managed to hide the div on page load but cant toggle it to show and hide. Here is my code:

```
<a class="clicker" href="#">Click here</a>

<div class="slider home-border-center" id="#">
blah blah blah
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".slider").hide();

    JQuery(".clicker").click(function(){
        JQuery(".slider").toggle();
    });
});

</script>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

JQuery

to:

jQuery

Because variable and function names are case-sensitive.

So:

```
<a class="clicker" href="#">Click here</a>

<div class="slider home-border-center" id="#">
blah blah blah
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".slider").hide();

    jQuery(".clicker").click(function(){
        jQuery(".slider").toggle();
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Wow silly me, and here was me thinking I was causing some kind of conflict! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Please mark your question as answered, if it helped.